# strip/gsub revert in ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm currently creating a title slugged version with the following.

```
title_slug = self.title.downcase.strip.gsub(' ', '-').gsub(/[^\w-]/, '')
```

In some cases I receive the slug and I should convert it back to the original name.

Is there any easy way to do the inverse of the code above (revert a slug name back to its original name.) in ruby ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your slugification function:

```
.downcase.strip.gsub(' ', '-').gsub(/[^\w-]/, '')
```

is clearly a non-invertible function so you can't go back simply. If you need to go back, you have a couple options:

1. Store the slug in your database so that you can query it.
2. Implement your slugification function in your database language (SQL, JavaScript, ...) so that, again, you can query on it.

In either case, you'll get duplicates when you query by slug so either you prevent duplicates in the first place (by modifying the slugs to force uniqueness) or you figure out some way to pick which of the results you want.

Answer (score 4):

Well, no. You're *removing information* from the string (deleting all letters that aren't alphanumerics, for example), so you can't reconstruct them afterwards.

You can't even safely convert dashes back into spaces - they might have been dashes in the original string. (Thanks @XavierHolt!)

Comment: You can't even safely convert dashes back into spaces - it might have been a dash in the original string.  @Martin: Better to store the original string and create the slug when you need it, since that direction, at least, is easy.

Comment: @XavierHolt I'm trying to do the opposite (I already store the original string and I'm receiving requests to the slugs)